# How does the ring sig work: practical explanation?

Tags: ringct, ring-signatures, ringdb

Is the following correct?:

If I received 5 XMR from Bob, then I wanted to send this 5 XMR to Alice.

Would I create a tx with the input as the 5 XMR from Bob with one output as 5 XMR to alice. Then look for another tx, fetch K inputs and outputs from that tx along with their public keys.

Then add those K inputs as inputs to my tx, along with the corresponding outputs for them. Because if we do not fetch the outputs, then inputs-outputs-fees != 0 and it would be rejected.

The tx is then signed with the ring signature using fetched keys + signer as the ring.

Interim Question: What is stopping me from fetching old inputs plus my own fresh input, then creating new outputs of my choosing, which spend the old inputs + my own? It would be valid since the keyImage I use will be the one for my new input, while the total would add up to my input + old inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then look for another tx, fetch K inputs and outputs from that tx along with their public keys.

You simply find decoy outputs from anywhere on the blockchain. You'd never only choose decoys from a single transaction.

> Then add those K inputs as inputs to my tx, along with the corresponding outputs for them

There is no need to match inputs and outputs from other transactions. The ring signature proves that for at least one combination of inputs, the inputs balance out with the outputs and fees.

Comment: If we do not match the decoy inputs to outputs in the tx, will it not be balanced? As in inputs-outputs-fees would not equal zero.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that we fetch decoy inputs to put into the new tx? The alternative would be to fetch to decoy tx's and sign multiple txs

Comment: You don't need the inputs-outputs-fees to match except for in one particular combination of the outputs (the ones you're really spending). All RingCT outputs are given a global sequential index, and random indices are selected so that those outputs can be referenced as decoy inputs in a transaction. The algorithm never looks at transactions - it looks directly at outputs.

Comment: How does the algorithm know which tx's are decoys and therefore we should not do the `input-output-fees` calculation? If I can summarise what you have said, when we add the decoys, we only need to add their inputs because the algorithm knows they are decoys and therefore they are only used for ring signature privacy.

Comment: The point of decoys is that it is impossible to know which inputs are decoys and which are the real outpus being spent. Just like the ring signature proves that you know the private key for one of the public keys (but not which public key), the ring signature proves that one of the combinations of inputs and outputs sums to zero, but not which.

Comment: So here is contradicting statement.

1. In order to verify a tx, we need to ensure that the inputs equal out the outputs. You mentioned that this should only be the case with the input that is being spent, but the validator does not know which input is being spent and which are decoys. I know you are correct by the way.

Comment: input PCs - output PCs - fee PC = PC to zero, where PC means Pedersen Commitment. Only when there is a zero PC will the private key of that zero PC be knowable, because a PC is amount*H + mask*G and the amount is zero, the PC will be simply mask*G. Since H=xG where x is universally unknowable, it's only possible to know the private key for a PC in the form mask*G (which will be simply the mask). There are multiple possible commitments to zero, and only the private key to one of them is knowable. The MLSAG demonstrates one private key is known for one of the possible candidate zero PCs.

Comment: I understand this. My problem is that I cannot understand how the Pederson Commitment will be zero, when you have decoy inputs amongst the real input. While the decoy inputs are not being spent.

Comment: Let's say you are spending a single input in a ring size of 7. As a verifier, there are  7 different versions of "outputs PCs-input PC-fee PC=result PC". All of these results PCs will look like random public keys because the verifier won't know the masks. Only where the result PC is actually a zero PC will the private key be knowable. This is the perfect opportunity for a ring signature to prove that a private key is known for one of those 7 public keys! (and therefore that it is a PC to zero). This is a simplification of how the MLSAG is proving that in one combination, it sums to zero.

Comment: I think I understand now. In this way, if we add more inputs the verifier will have to check more combinations to find the correct zero PC. Thanks for riding this out, I will read more papers and be back pretty soon :)